# Debug Assertion Failed - MSVCP110D.dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string token = "000000:::AAAA:::000011:::Hello 8:::::::D Jay!";
    string * stringArray = new string[token.size()]; 
    string interim;
    int r = 0;
    int arrayCounter = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < token.length(); x++)
    {
        if(token[x] != ':')
        {

            interim[r] = token[x];
            r++;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < r; x++)
    {
        cout << interim[x] << endl;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am new and learning, and have narrowed it down to the line:

```
            interim[r] = token[x];
```

..But i don't know why it crashes. Advice?  I am coding in Visual C++ VSE2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `interim` has a size of zero.  Setting `interim[r] = token[x]` modifies the string at location `r` without changing its size.  With a size of zero this is undefined behavior.

`interim += token[x]` is probably what you want.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string token = "000000:::AAAA:::000011:::Hello 8:::::::D Jay!";
    string interim;

    for(int x = 0; x < token.length(); x++)
    {
        if(token[x] != ':')
        {
            interim += token[x];
        }
    }

    cout << interim << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
000000AAAA000011Hello 8D Jay!
Press any key to continue . . .
```